# It is possible to use ng-bootstrap when the project was created to use sass?

Tags: angular, sass, ng-bootstrap

We started our first Angular 4 project created using CLI and set it to use SASS style.

We knew about ng-bootstrap and would like to used it.

would be possible to use ng-bootstrap in this case since it uses CSS?

Comment: These type of questions are not practiced in StackOverflow.

Comment: @Aravind, what is the issue that you are seeing that I didn't get from your comment?